# PostgreSQL/plpython: how compare two columns from different table in loop

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem with loop in which I must compare columns between different tables.

I have two tables `year2004` and `year2005`. Both contains month numbers and an amount for that month. I want compare the amount from both tables and produce a third table `year` with the number of month and greatest amount for that month.

For example I have in 2004 - 100, in 2005 - 200 so I must return values(2005, number_of_month, 200). Have you any ideas for solve this problem?

PS. Sorry for my writing errors, I learned English only few years ago :)

Comment: Most probably you won't need a _loop_. Just join the two tables and compare/substract them. BTW: it would help if you _at least_ would add the table definitions to your question. Plus _what_ you intend to compare, and your intended result.

Comment: I wrote that i compare only amount but in result I would like to have year, number of month and max amount.

my table:

create table year2004(
month int,
amount int)

table year2005 the same. table with results:
create table results(
year int,
month int,
amount int)

Comment: Generally sample data - table definitions and contents - really help with this kind of question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm *guessing* that you're trying to find *the greatest amount for each month* across the two years.

This would be much, much easier if your data was all in one table `monthly_statistics` with a `date` column. Then it'd just be a simple aggregate function or a window.

So lets turn the two tables into one.

Given sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE year2004 ( month int primary key, amount int);
INSERT INTO year2004 (month, amount)
VALUES (1, 50), (2, 40), (3, 60), (4, 80), (5, 100), (6, 800), (7, 20), (8, 40), (9, 30), (10, 40), (11, 50), (12, 99);

CREATE TABLE year2005 ( month int primary key, amount int);
INSERT INTO year2005 (month, amount)
VALUES (1, 88), (2, 44), (3, 11), (4, 123), (5, 12), (6, 88), (7, 21), (8, 19), (9, 44), (10, 89), (11, 4), (12, 42);
```

we could either join the tables, or we could convert it to a single table by date then filter it. Here's how we might generate a single table with the contents:

```
SELECT DATE '2004-01-01' + month * INTERVAL '1' MONTH AS sampledate, amount
FROM year2004
UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2005-01-01' + month * INTERVAL '1' MONTH, amount
FROM year2005;
```

That's what you'd use if you were going to create a new table, but if you don't care about the actual dates, only the months, you can simply union all the two tables:

```
WITH samples AS (
  SELECT month, amount
  FROM year2004
  UNION ALL
  SELECT month, amount 
  FROM year2005
)
SELECT month, max(amount) AS amount 
FROM samples 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY month;

 samplemonth | amount 
-------------+--------
           5 |    123
          11 |     89
           1 |     99
           2 |     88
           3 |     44
           9 |     40
           4 |     60
           6 |    100
          10 |     44
          12 |     50
           7 |    800
           8 |     21
(12 rows)
```

Comment: this is the task from classess so i can't add other table with date ;/ date i can add only in insert after compare amount. so i have from year2004 (1, 200) and from year2005(1,300) and i must insert into new table (2005, 1, 300).